# Using AWS with SVN

Tags: git, visual-studio, svn, amazon-web-services

*Setting the scene:*

I'm trying to find a good low-cost solution for controlling and organising the development of an application on Visual Studio by a small team of developers (5 people).

Firstly, we searched the web for a good versioning software. The team has little experience with SVN (TortoiseSVN), but there are new solutions nowadays, the famous Git. There are lots of discussions about which one is better, but that's not the case here. Both SVN and Git would meet our needs, so they both are a valid option.

As we've already acquired some Google services, we thought of using our storage space on Google Drive together with the software versioning. Researches over the web showed that it is not a good idea to do so, as some incompatibility surprises might occur.

Then, we step up on the Amazon Web Services, which presents a good price for a great service. Again, researches over the internet resulted on some tutorials about configuring the AWS to use SVN. But these tutorials are not clear if we choose to use Windows Server (most of them use Ubuntu or Linux). And also, I didn't quite understand if I need to focus on the AWS EC2 or just the AWS S3.

*Summarizing, the question:*

**How can I use and configure AWS to run a SVN/Git for developing a application by a small number of users (5 developers)? And is there a significant difference between using SVN or Git regarding the easiness of using/configuring it?**

*Extra question:*

Is there any better way of accomplish the described task (storing on a safe place an on-development application while using SVN/Git)?

*Note1: I don't want to create a discussion about which service is better or worse, my focus is on finding the best (i.e. the easiest) solution for my situation.*

*Note2: I don't know if it makes any difference, but it is not a web application.*

Comment: This isn't a very good question for Stack Overflow. It's opinion-based and broadly focused, both reasons for questions to be closed here. Having said that, have you looked at [Visual Studio Online](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/what-is-visual-studio-online-vs.aspx)? You seem to be very Microsoft-focused, so it might be a good fit.

Comment: If you're considering git as an option then I'd strongly recommend using a service like [Github](https://github.com/pricing) which offers private repos (fully backed up) starting at around $7/month. That way you don't have to worry about managing your own AWS instance, installing & configuring git yourself, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use AWS EC2 based solution for this. Especially because it's a small team. It would may makes sense only if your source code is extremely secret and you have to manage the Source code repository because of legacy reasons.

Since you are using Visual Studio, I'm happy to promote [visualstudioonline.com](http://visualstudioonline.com) for you. It is free up to 5 person without a VSO licence or there is a really good, $45/month/developer deal, which also covers a Visual Studio professional licence. ( My team is just started to use this service.)

It has several features, one of them is a free, TFS or GIT based version controlling service.

Other option is [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/). I'm using this for my git repositories. It's free up to 5 users, has JIRA integration and other features.

And I almost forget [AWS Commit](http://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/) which is a really good source control system used by Amazon internally. This service will be public in the close future, we are all really waiting for it!